# Polymorphism fails in python class derived from C++ extensions with SWIG tool and directors

Tags: python, c++, polymorphism, swig

I have some 3rd party C++ extension codes which I hope to use in my python code. So I started to use SWIG to help, which supports C++ so nicely. As SWIG said on http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/SWIGDocumentation.html#Python_directors , it can support polymorphism, so I used following codes, but I encountered some strange problems.

I have c++ .h codes like this:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void foo(){std::cout<<"A foo"<<endl;};
};

class B
{
public:
    A *a = nullptr;
};

extern A *g_a;
```

And I have c++ .cpp codes like this:

```
A *g_a = nullptr;
```

My .i file is like this:

```
%module(directors="1") A    
%{
#include "A.h"
extern A *g_a;
%}    
%feature("director") A;
%include "A.h";
```

My py file is like this:

```
import A  

class ASub(A.A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ASub, self).__init__()

    def foo(self):
        super(ASub, self).foo()
        print "ASub foo"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bb = A.B()
    bb.a = ASub()
    bb.a.foo()       # only print "A foo", but no "ASub foo"

    A.cvar.g_a = ASub()
    A.cvar.g_a.foo() # this line will give three random results when run in
                     # serveral times, 1) the python interpreter crashes, 
                     # 2) gives a traceback saying it has no attribute, 
                     # 3) just print "A foo", without "ASub foo"
```

Normally I hope I can get "A foo" and "ASub foo" with ASub.foo is called in each way, but it didnt work as I expected. Can anybody help to explain this?

But the way, code below works! WHY??!!

```
//c++, which is in module A
void update(A *a)
{
    a->foo();
}
//python
my_a = ASub()
A.update(my_a)
```

The above code gives "A foo" and "ASub foo". I'm really confused!

Comment: What is your python version, and if under 3.0, does A inherits from object?

Comment: @RodrigoLópez, looking at the print statement it looks like 2.x

Comment: @RodrigoLópez the python version is 2.7, swig version is 3.0.5. A is a c++ class, I just want to derive a new class from A in python. According to the generated code by swig, I think the transformed class inherits from object.